# How to place 2 divs parallel to each other in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have tried col-xs-6 first child and other things. Please specify how to do it using bootstrap only.

I tried col-xs-6 not working. I wanted to place these divs right next to each other or we can say parallel to each other but it made no change.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container-md bg-danger center-block ">
      <form>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-center">
            <label for="job-name">Type job name</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-lg border-success text-center rounded-circle " id="job-name " rows="3" placeholder="Job-name">
          </div>
          
          <div>
            <label for="first-name">Type first name</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="border-dark form-control-lg-mb2 mt-2 ml-2 text-center rounded-right" id="first-name" rows="3" placeholder="first Name" required><br>
          </div>
          
          <div class="align-self-right">
            <label for="last-name">Type last name</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="border-dark form-control-lg-mb2 ml-2 text-center rounded-right" id="last-name" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your last Name" required><br>
          </div>
          
          <div class="align-self-right">
            <label for="last-name">Type Phone number</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="border-dark form-control-lg-mb2 ml-2 rounded-right" id="last-name" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your Number"><br>
          </div>
          
          <div class="align-self-right">
            <label for="last-name">Type Email</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="border-dark form-control-lg-mb2 ml-2 rounded-right" id="last-name" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your Email"><br>
          </div>
          
          <div class="align-self-right">
            <label for="last-name"> Age</label><br>
            <input type="date" class="border-dark form-control-lg-mb2 ml-2 rounded-right" id="last-name" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your last Name"><br>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-right">
            <label for="last-name"> Age</label><br>
            <input type="date" class="border-dark form-control-lg-mb2 ml-2 rounded-right" id="last-name" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your last Name"><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does "parallel" mean here? Why are you using two containers? Please revise to explain more clearly what you want. If it's just two columns, follow [the grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/#example) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just places the columns inside a row and it will work like how you expect it to.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">column 1</div>
<div class="col-6">column 2</div>
</div>
```

In you case the form is breaking the flow so place the row inside the form

```
<form>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">column 1</div>
<div class="col-6">column 2</div>
</div>
</form>
```